# Best method for defining layers using tf keras api?

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow.keras api not working on while creating the layers reference, any other methods of creating layers reference?
code : 
layer=keras.layers

Error message : NameError: name 'leyer' is not defined

Full code is pasted here...

```
import tensorflow as tf   
from tensorflow import keras   
import pandas as pd   
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold   
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score   
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder   
import numpy as np   

#makin seed values   
seed=7   
np.random.seed(seed)   

#setting up the dataset for training    
dataframe=pd.read_csv("../datasets/iris.csv",header=None)   
data=dataframe.values   
input_x = data[:,0:4]   
true_y = data[:,4]    

#Encoding the true_y data to one hot encoding   
le=LabelEncoder()   
le.fit(true_y)    
y_encoded = le.transform(true_y)    
y_encoded = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_encoded,num_classes=3)    

# creating the model    
def base_fun():    
    layer=keras.layers     
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layer.Dense(4,input_dim=4,kernel_initializer='normal',activation='relu'))   
    model.add(leyer.Dense(3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))     

estimator=keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(build_fn=base_fun,epochs=20,batch_size=10)     
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)    
result = cross_val_score(estimator, input_x, y_encoded,cv=kfold)    

print("Accuracy : %.2%% (%.2%%)" %(result.mean()*100, result.std()*100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this line:

```
model.add(leyer.Dnese(3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
```

has two typos, namely `leyer` should be `layer` and `Dnese` should be `Dense` like

```
model.add(layer.Dense(3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
```

Based on your comment, this line also causes an error:

```
estimator = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier( build_fn = base_fun, epochs = 20, batch_size = 10 )
```

From the [Keras Scikit documentation](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/):

> build_fn should construct, compile and return a Keras model, which will then be used to fit/predict.

But you function `base_fun()` does not return anything. Append this line at the end of `base_fun()`:

```
return model
```

As per your comment, the last `print` line could be changed to this (I don't know the % formatting, I generally use the syntax below):

```
print( "Accuracy : {:.2%} ({:.2%})".format( result.mean(), result.std() ) )
```

Comment: Yup, but another problem arrived. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loss', shows in line 34

Comment: Added more info to answer in response to your comment

Comment: Ys I added compile method and returns it. But makes error on lase printing result a last. I have experienced same error when it executed on using Keras itself.
Error is 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iris_example.py", line 38, in <module>
    print("Accuracy : %.2%% (%.2%%)" %(result.mean()*100, result.std()*100))
ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 17


Anyway thanks